grouping jobs in prometheus.yaml
in prometheus.yaml I can add jobs via
 - job_name: 'A'
    options...
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9090', ...]
  - job_name: 'B'
  ...

and in alerting_rules.yaml I can place several alerts for different jobs or several jobs
groups:
- name: alerting
  rules:
  - alert: InstanceDown
    expr: up{'A', 'B'}  == 0

Is it possible to group jobs already in prometheus.yaml like
 - group A
     - job_name: 'A'
     - job_name: 'B'
 - group B 
     - job_name: 'C'
     - job_name: 'A'

so that I can assign alerting rules to that groups (like expr: up{'group A'}  == 0). At the moment I have a huge number of job_names and there no specification in the alerting rules (expr: up  == 0). Now I want to add jobs to prometheus.yaml with should be assigned to a different alert without specifying all current job in the current alert.
